# php random name

Tags: php

HI

Whats the best way to create a random name for a folder?

Its going to be used for a folder name to store documents. But lots of folders are going to be created and so need it to be unique each time if possible.

Length should probably be around 7 characters.

Comment: Any preference as to how long it should be? What is this going to be used for? More info please.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If it needs to be unique, then I would forget about it being random and just increment a counter.  If you need to associate the contents of the folders with records in a database, all the better.  You can just have an autoincrement column in your database and use it as part of the folder name.

Comment: That assumes he's already using a database and/or doesn't mind the overhead.

Comment: @BraynH: That's why I said "if".  You can still implement a counter in PHP, it's just more convenient if you're associating the contents with a database record anyway.

Answer (score 13):

You can also try PHP's [`uniqid()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.uniqid.php), with the param `more_entropy` set to true.

Or just [`sha1(`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)[`microtime()`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php)[`)`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/function.sha1.php)

Comment: This is the only sensible answer here. +1.

Comment: Isn't microtime() only available on *NIX? http://us3.php.net/manual/en/function.microtime.php

Comment: No, it's just called an UNIX timestamp, but available on all systems.

Answer (score 3):

Here's the function I use:

```
function makeRandomString($max=6) {
    $i = 0; //Reset the counter.
    $possible_keys = "0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $keys_length = strlen($possible_keys);
    $str = ""; //Let's declare the string, to add later.
    while($i<$max) {
        $rand = mt_rand(1,$keys_length-1);
        $str.= $possible_keys[$rand];
        $i++;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

EDIT: As Bill the Lizard said, you'd better add some kind of counter. Although very unlikely, it is possible that the same string can be created twice.

Comment: instead of using a counter you could also use http://us.php.net/file_exists to check if the folder already exists.

Answer (score 2):

Is 7 char folder name a hard and fast rule (what is the cause of the limit)?

I use YYYYmmDDHHMMSS (and add millisecond if you find yourself getting many collisions).

Where

- YYYY = four digit date
- mm = two digit month
- DD = two digit day
- HH = two digit (24hr) hour
- MM = two digit minute
- SS = two digit second

You may also want to test to see if the directory has already been created and then sleep for a random number of milliseconds before trying again.

PHP Code:

```
<?php
$dirName = date( 'YmdHis', time() );
@mkdir( $dirName )
?>
```

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need it to be random?

If you need it to be unique I'd suggest creating a counter and converting the integer number to hex or even better base 36(26 chars + 10 digits).
After creating the folder increase the counter and you're good to go.

Answer (score 1):

php has a standard function, tmpnam that does exactly that; it creates a unique file name (actually creates the file, but can delete and use as folder later :)

Answer (score 0):

with the requirement that it be unique and 7 characters i'd probably use a number encoded to base 36 (0-9 and a-z), that way you can just see what the last folder was and incrememnt it to create a new one.

Answer (score 0):

#### "rh" . mt_rand(10000,99999)

Then check to see if it's unique and regenerate if it isn't. In a way this is better than saving state, like a counter, because less can go wrong.

```
do {
  $f = "rh" . mt_rand(10000,99999);
} while (file_exists($f));
```

Answer (score 0):

I think best approach to naming is using uniqid() function.

```
$folder_name = uniqid();// eg: 4b3403665fea6
```

or with a static prefix:

```
$folder_name = uniqid('folder_'));// eg: folder_537834f6e981a
```

or with today (date) prefix:

```
$folder_name = uniqid(date('h-i-s')._); //eg: 04-23-59_537835dff2017
```

Answer (score 0):

In this example we can look a random key with min and max length.

```
substr(str_shuffle("0123456789abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"), 0, $length)
```