# Saving Images to folder | PHP

Tags: php, image, saving-data

I want to be able to open the provided URL (which is done via a form) that is an URL that will allow the server to save the file into a directory, for example:

```
http://www.google.co.uk/intl/en_com/images/srpr/logo1w.png
```

I want to save that logo into this directory:

```
img/logos/
```

Then it will add it to the database by giving it a random file name before so, e.g.

```
827489734.png
```

It will now be inserted to the database with the following:

```
img/logos/827489734.png
```

I do not want to use cURL for this, I like to work with fopen, file_get_contents, etc...

Cheers.

**EDIT**

```
$logo = safeInput($_POST['logo']);

if(filter_var($avatar, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL))
{
    $get_logo = file_get_contents($logo);
    $logo_directory = 'img/logos/';

    $save_logo = file_put_contents($logo_directory, $logo);

    if($save_logo)
    {
        $logo_path = $logo_directory . $save_logo;
```

A part of this code I need helping...

Comment: ` I like to work with fopen, file_get_contents, etc...` well, then get to work! What is your question? Where are you stuck?

Comment: Alright, alright! No need to get mouthy like that, I've edited the post...

Comment: @YouBook what is the problem with the code, what doesn't work? Looks okay so far.

Comment: as in the `if($save_logo){` point, it outputs the else, which says "Error saving image" for what I call...

Comment: Who says "error saving" exactly - PHP? If so, what's the exact error message? What does the path look like that you're saving to? Do you have write rights to that directory?

Comment: `} else { echo "Error saving image" }` - that's what it says as I said... the PHP file is in the root of the server and the logos is placed `<root>/img/logos/` which it is not saving it to.

Comment: @YouBook turn error reporting on (`error_reporting(E_ALL);`) and see what it says after the file_put_contents. Does your script have write permissions to that directory?

Comment: It doesn't say anything, I'm working on Localhost on my Mac, so the permissions should be fine.

Comment: @You there is no message if you put the error reporting line to the top of your script?

Comment: @You I don't understand your last comment, what is that in response to?

Comment: I mean I have put the error_reporting at the top of the script `<?php error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: @You strange. `file_put_contents()` is returning false, so there must be an error, and an error message. Is error reporting on? (Use `phpinfo()` to find out)

Comment: It says error_reporting is 6143

Comment: @You sorry, I mean `display_errors`

Comment: Ah, now I know why... says Off... FML

Comment: Now it says: `Warning: file_put_contents(img/logos/) [function.file-put-contents]: failed to open stream: Is a directory in /Applications/MAMP/htdocs/update/process.php on line 56`

Comment: @You ahh, of course, you need to specify a file name - the directory i s not enough. Check SO to find your favourite function to build a random name/ID, but take note of the accepted answer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1488288/php-random-name see e.g. here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3347521/random-id-number-generator-in-php

Comment: Cheers for the help, helped a lot. I know this process was a pain but it was worth it in the end. ;)

Comment: @YouBook you're welcome. I'll add an answer so this can be closed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to specify a full file name when doing a `file_put_contents()`. A pure directory name won't cut it.